# What is going on with my Facebook sharing solution (and my google plus share solution)?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Please read the following disclaimer first: I have made every effort, for the past hour or so, to figure out this issue.  Google, experimenting, searching stackoverflow, etc.  And I have been unable to figure this issue out.  It may be considered a "duplicate" to some, or many, but I want to make my efforts clear so that any accusations of this being a duplicate will hopefully at least be fair.  Thank you.

I am working on a site at the following temp URL:

http://jrltest.host-ed.me/index.html

I have developed a JS solution for the sharing buttons (top-ish right) using each social media's "manual" or "custom" sharing solution.  That is to say, the solution that allows me to type what URL I would like to share in the "sharing" link.  My site is using SSI, and the share buttons are one of the "included" files, so it is not even a possible solution to manually type in the URL, as there is only one share button per social media platform.  Even if the share button was on every page, however, it would still not be a feasible solution.  I put together the following js file:

http://jrltest.host-ed.me/_js/share.js

This simply assigns a Variable to document.URL and document.title, which I can then insert those variables, as needed, into the custom URL.

I'm experiencing some oddities, however, that I can't quite figure out with both the FB and Google Plus share button.  The twitter button is the only one that is behaving exactly as expected.  I'll outline the issues below numerically.

1: Facebook issue.  When visiting the following URL: http://jrltest.host-ed.me/index.html and clicking on the FB share button, a popup box opens and displays the Title as, "James River Laser & Equipment Home".  However, my current Home pages title is, "James River Laser and Equipment Home".  The title USED to be, "James River Laser & Equipment Home", however, the twitter URL uses the '&' symbol to separate their parameters and it cuts off everything after the '&'.  I have no idea where it is getting that title from, however, as it has been changed.  If you visit the "About" page, however, the FB share button shows, "Untitled Document" as the title of the page to be shared.  And I do have a proper title specified on the about page.

2: Facebook issue.  The following issue is related to issue number 1, however, it is the result of an attempt to fix the first issue.  I figured out (thanks to one of the stackoverflow questions I found) that I can pass in a custom title in addition to a custom URL.  So I modified my FB share URL to the following:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+currentURL+"?t="+currentTitle

When I used this URL, the Home page shows, "document.title" as the title, BUT the About page shows, "About Our Company" as the title.  I can't even begin to guess why it's working for the About page, but not for the Home page.  They both have a proper title, and if I open up the console and type, "document.title" it returns the expected, "James River Laser and Equipment Home"...yet it is still showing "document.title" in the FB pop up box.

3: Google Plus issue.  When visiting the following URL: http://jrltest.host-ed.me/index.html and clickign on the GPlus share button, a popup box opens and displays the Title as, "James River Laser & Equipment HomeHeaderShare Our PageFooter".  This is unusual and a bit confusing as well.  Earlier today, and previously, my SSI pages were HTML documents, complete with a head tags, title tags, body tags, everything.  And I gave those pages titles relevant to what they were.  "Header" was the title given to my menu header, "Share Our Page" was the title given to my social share section, and "Footer" was the title given to the footer at the bottom.  However, I have since stripped these documents of everything except the content and the content tags (divs and li, etc) but Google plus is STILL showing the description like this.  Something even stranger, though, is that if you visit the home page at the following URL: http://jrltest.host-ed.me and click on the GPlus share button, it now shows only, "James River Laser & Equipment Home" as the title.  Which is better, but I still don't know where it's getting this from, as the pages title is, "James River Laser and Equipment Home".

I realize the Facebook sharer that I'm using is depreciated, but I have not yet been able to figure out whatever replacement solution Facebook is providing.  They keep talking about Apps (even if I click for use on web) and nothing is explained well enough for someone with my limited skills to understand.

I'm still looking into this problem to try and figure it out myself, as I always do, but I don't feel like I'll be able to do this alone.  So I'm hoping someone out there will know what's going on, and can give me a run down.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no way any more to set the additional parameters for sharing on FB dynamically at runtime – the Share dialog takes the URL of the object to share as its _only_ parameter, and all other values are fetched from that URL.

Comment: well that certainly can't be true, because when I set the '?t=' parameter (as mentioned in detail on issue number 2) it passed in the correct page title of, "About Our Company" on the about page.  However, on the homepage, it passed in the variable pointing to document.title as if it were a string, instead of actually grabbing the title of the document (It displayed the title as, "document.title"). Regardless, I am inquiring about why I am getting such odd behavior. I know I've overlooked something, I just can't figure out what.  Thanks!

Comment: You are drawing the wrong conclusions here … Your about page _has_ the title `About Our Company` in the `title` element in the HTML, so Facebook _has_ grabbed in from there … and has _ignored_ your attempt to pass the title via `?t=`, as I already told you it would.

Comment: And with the home page, that’s also simple, because the HTML document actually contains `<meta property="og:title" content=document.title />` … by which you are actively _telling_ Facebook that `document.title` was the text that should be used as the title when sharing this URL …

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjrltest.host-ed.me%2Fabout.html show the title as `About Our Company`, and so does https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fjrltest.host-ed.me%2Fabout.html … if your results differ, then that might be a cache problem from your previous tries or something. https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fjrltest.host-ed.me%2Fabout.html&t=something+else however does _not_ show a different title, but still `About Our Company` … because, as I told you, FB ignores these additional parameters now.

Comment: And https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjrltest.host-ed.me%2Findex.html also shows, that Facebook _grabs `document.title` from your HTML_ (and it _is_ in your HTML code of that document).

Comment: And the address you said you used to _try_ and pass a title to Facebook is technically wrong as well: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+currentURL+"?t="+currentTitle` – the question mark is only used to begin the Query String, after that, additional parameter=value pairs are separated from the first one by an ampersand.

Comment: this is incredibly frustrating. I tested multiple times earlier and the results were consistent, which is why I was so confident.  But I can admit when I'm wrong, and I apologize.  It is, however, still acting odd, but it must be some caching problem.  Just a few minutes ago when I was playing with it, it correctly displayed the title, "James River Laser and Equipment", but now it's back to displaying, "document.title".  And I pulled that meta tag out right away.  Please reply in the form of an answer so that I can give you appropriate credit for your help.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries :-) I understand stuff like this can be frustrating, and patience can run a little short when that happens. (And did so on my part as well, so let me apologize too.)

Comment: Not a problem at all :-)  If it wasn't for what you had said, I wouldn't have checked it out on my home computer and realized that it was a caching issue of some sort.  I did some tests and made some changes based on the information you gave me and found that I had embarrassed myself :P  With the tools you've provided though, and the information, I should have no problems with these buttons anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to recap:

Passing anything else than just the URL of the page to share on Facebook is not possible any more – it was some time ago, but they removed that, and now the title, description, image etc. are pulled from the document itself.
Preferably they are to be set via Open Graph meta elements (http://ogp.me/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/), but if those are not found, Facebook will take the information from the HTML directly – by looking at the `title` element, a (not Open Graph-specific) description meta element, the embedded images etc.

Caching can be an issue with testing this and changing values – but by using their [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), you can see what information Facebook is currently seeing on your page, what “errors” there might be Open Graph-wise … and it will clear their cache of the document as well.

Apart from caching problems, your issues during testing seem to have been from wrong information within the documents (`<meta property="og:title" content=document.title />` leading to `document.title` showing up as document title), and a misconception of the effect of the `t` parameter passed to the dialog (which as stated does not work any more).

---

If you are still experiencing problems with your G+ share, they have a test tool as well: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I wasn't aware of those testing tools, and they will be invaluable, as the caching issue seems to be very stubborn (and caused a lot of frustrating and confusion for me haha).  Thank you again, very much!